# Need suggestions on dumping formatted data from table to file given restrictions

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Long story short is we have a table that is created as a result of a process and at the end of that process we need to extract it to a local file with a delimiter like a pipe between the columns (sometimes they want a TAB or comma, whatever).  Sounds simple, but we do not have access to the database's local filesystem and cannot write to a directory object or to a file via UTL_FILE calls.  The database actually lives on a vendor owned system across the country from us and is accessed through a VPN.

In order to get output to a local file here, from our Windows 7 environment we have been using a .vbs program (this is part of a bigger process flow) to call a .sql wrapper script via sqlplus that simply spools output to a local file and calls the procedure which uses DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() in a row by row cursor (I know, slow by slow), whose output is formatted then captured to the file by spool.  This is clunky but ok for small tables but now we have a couple of multi-million row tables and performance writing is unacceptable.

There must be a better way as tools like Toad can dump the huge tables out in no time to a local folder under the same restrictions so they must be using some kind of Oracle-foo that I can't seem to discover how to do myself.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using PL/SQL to query the table, rather than just a straight SQL query?

Comment: @Alex Poole I'm sorry If I wasn't clear.  An existing procedure truncates then builds the table fresh with each run, performs a bunch of updates, etc then the last thing it does is read the rows via the cursor, builds a string with the delimiters and uses PUT_LINE(), which the wrapper .sql catches and writes a row at a time (groan).  I should say I'm trying to improve the writing to the file part, which could be moved to the .sql wrapper for sure.

Comment: sqlplus has a `COLSEP` `SET` command which could be set to the delimiter.  I will explore this.  Perhaps this could be set, then simply select everything from the table, after setting the options to suppress headings, etc.

Comment: You end up with a lot of whitespace doing that though, and still need to make sure dates etc. are formatted as expected; and any strings that contain your delimiter can cause problems, It's a bit more work but I usually explicitly concatenate the delimiter as part of the query.

Comment: @alex poole yes me too and that is what the original code in the procedure is doing.  I am grasping at anything to speed up writing 21 million rows to a file.  :-/

Comment: I'm missing something then... if your procedure has a cursor that does that formatting and concatenation, then can't you just pull the cursor query out into plain SQL?

Comment: @alex poole Basically yes, the cursor query selects the columns, then there is a cursor for loop that builds the records with the delimiters.  That is what I want to rework.  It can be done in plain SQL and eliminate the cursor.  It will be interesting to see what the timing difference will be by just eliminating the cursor.  Do you think that's all that tools like Toad are doing under the covers after you set the formatting options that let them dump so fast?

Answer (score 1):

Try unloading the table by parallel scripts in separate files and then merge the files. Just have to figure out key for ranges.

Optional:
If you have a luxury of partitioning then you could unload each partition by separate script in parallel.

I also was curious how slow is slow-by-slow compared to select and for bulk collect, and made a quick benchmark measuring by wall clock (set timing on on SQL*Plus)

```
akra@XE> DROP TABLE t_big;

Table dropped.

akra@XE> CREATE TABLE t_big TABLESPACE USERS AS
  2  SELECT *
  3    FROM (SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE rownum <= 200)
  4    JOIN (SELECT 1 FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
  5      ON 1 = 1;

Table created.

akra@XE>
akra@XE> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_big;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    200000
```

1. SELECT made a file on my machine in 00:00:39.36

   ```
   SET feedback OFF
   SET timing ON
   SET TERMOUT OFF   
   spool c:\temp\sel.txt
   SELECT Owner||'|'||object_name||'|'||object_type line FROM t_big;
   spool OFF
   ```
2. Slow by slow made it in 00:01:04.98

   ```
   spool c:\temp\for.txt
   DECLARE
     i PLS_INTEGER:=0;
   BEGIN
     dbms_output.enable(1000000);
     FOR r IN (SELECT owner || '|' 
       || object_name || '|' 
       || object_type line FROM t_big) 
     LOOP
       i := i + 1;
       IF MOD(i, 1000)=0 THEN
         dbms_output.enable(1000000); --Reset buffer to avoid buffer overflow
       END IF;
       dbms_output.put_line(r.line);
     END LOOP;
   END;
   /
   spool OFF
   ```
3. Bulk Collect approach took  00:01:05.08

   ```
      spool c:\temp\blk.txt
       DECLARE
         TYPE t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
         vt t;
         CURSOR c IS
           SELECT owner || '|' 
             || object_name || '|' 
             || object_type line FROM t_big;
       BEGIN
         OPEN c;
         LOOP
           FETCH c BULK COLLECT
             INTO vt LIMIT 1001;
               dbms_output.enable(1000000);
           FOR i IN 1 .. vt.count LOOP
             dbms_output.put_line(vt(i));
           END LOOP;
           EXIT WHEN vt.count=0;
         END LOOP;
       END;
       /
       spool OFF
   ```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for going through the trouble.